# Does Nim support types with immutable fields?

Tags: immutability, nim-lang

In C# you can do this

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Foo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo("Foo Object");

    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);

    // Will not compile
    // foo.Name = "Bar Object";
}
```

Can you do the same (or something that has the intended effect) in Nim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nim doesn't have encapsulation on type scope (and it wouldn't make sense since Nim is not an object oriented language, all data processing is separated from the data itself).
The same effect can be achieved using module-scope encapsulation like this:

foo.nim:

```
type Foo* = ref object
    name: string

proc newFoo*(name: string): Foo =
    new result
    result.name = name

proc name*(self: Foo): string =
    self.name
```

main.nim:

```
import foo

let f = newFoo("Foo Object")
echo f.name

# Error: attempting to call undeclared routine: 'name='
# f.name = "Bar Object"
```